# Adding target sub and parameters to a hyperlink in excel VBA

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I am new to VBA but have successfully managed to dynamically hyperlink text such that when it is clicked a sub is run. That sub needs an ID which nestles out of sight in a cell next to the hyperlink. The hyperlink handler picks up the ID and passes it to the sub. However, there isn't always space to include these hidden IDs. Is it possible to include the ID in the hyperlink itself? I have tried asigning it to the address and subaddress properties but an error is shown about not being able to find the link target...

"Cannot open the specified file"

Is there anywhere else in the hyperlink to put it?

Also, is it possible to put the sub to run inside the hyperlink so the job of the handler is easier?

Any help would be most welcome

Comment: Could you include an example of the cells, hyperlinks, and subs. I'm frankly not quite getting the whole picture.

Comment: Could you also please say how are you opening that hyperlink (Internet Explorer?)